# Getting not found http error with Openweathermap API

Tags: javascript, openweathermap

I'm trying to code a weather app that displays temperature according to your current location ,using OpenWeatherApi, I get an error 404 I don't know why

```js
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
      long = position.coords.longitude;
      lat = position.coords.latitude;
      console.log(position);
      const api = `api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${lat}&lon=${long}&appid=74913cd6ec927a299e7fd99534e17b5f`;
      fetch(api)
        .then(response => {
          return response.json();
        })
        .then(data => {
          console.log(data);
        });
    });
```

The error I'm getting in the console:

[image: error I get in the console]

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code. Are you sure that the long/lat and `appid` are valid?

Comment: I was having the same problem. You just solved it for me. Jah Bless You

Answer (score 2):

You need to prepend `https://` to your URL. For example,

❌ `api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat={lat}&lon={lon}&appid={API key}`

✅ `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat={lat}&lon={lon}&appid={API key}`

The API call on the OpenWeather occasionally excludes `https://` from their API call URLs on their website. However when making an API call in your JS code, you cannot omit this because otherwise your code will convert your URL to a relative path.

Answer (score 0):

You're not hitting their endpoint. Since you didn't provide a URL scheme, it's being recognized as a relative path and you're hitting your localhost.

Comment: Thank you, and how can I provide a URL scheme to their endpoint ?

Comment: (notice in your error it says "`get http://127.0.0.1:5500/api`" etc)